# How to add quotes to string in Swift?

Tags: swift, string

I want to add double quotes around specific substrings in a string viz.: "This is my "QuotedString" in statement".
I have tried :

```
let quotedString = String(format:"This is my \"%@\" in statement",QuotedString)
```

But this creates :
"This is my \"QuotedString\" in statement".

Comment: Your code should work. Question is "Where do you see that output"? Debugger? Try to put it into a `UILabel`, a `UITextView`, etc. and the backslash shouldn't appear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it doesn’t create `"This is my \"QuotedString\" in statement"`, with the backslashes included. It’s just that when you look at that in the debugger, it includes those backslashes to help you identify the quotes within quoted string (just like you did when you created the string).

But if you use that resulting string in a text field or label, and you’ll see it’s fine, that those backslashes are not really part of the string. Or look at the `count` of that string, and you’ll see that those backslashes are not included there, either. Those backslashes are merely a byproduct of how you happen to be examining this variable.

Comment: Thanks. I was stuck in debugging mode . It works. Although it prints \ while debugging .

Answer (score 1):

`\` are used as escape sequences in regular expression. While you are debugging your code, it evaluates it as regular expression. So you see `\` in string. Try to print string on console and see the output.